# TSQL: How to split a row in multiple rows based on the number in a cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I want to create a view that splits a row based on the number in the cell "QTY"

Row 1 has value 1 in cell "QTY" and should result in 1 row
Row 2 has value 2 in cell "QTY" and should result in 2 rows
Row 3 has value 4 in cell "QTY" and should result in 4 rows

**My table**

```
QTY  ITEM
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
4  | ccc
```

**My result should look like this**

```
QTY  ITEM
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
2  | bbb
4  | ccc
4  | ccc
4  | ccc
4  | ccc
```

**Create table**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
    [QTY] [int] NULL,
    [Item] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([QTY], [Item]) VALUES (1, N'aaa       ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([QTY], [Item]) VALUES (2, N'bbb       ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([QTY], [Item]) VALUES (4, N'ccc       ')
GO
```

Comment: What's the max value of `QTY`?

Comment: Also, by `QTY` do you mean `No`? Your table (`mytable`) contains no column `QTY`.

Comment: From 1 up to 185.

Comment: I have adjusted the column to name to QTY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution also using the `master.dbo.spt_values`.

```
create table MyTable (QTY int, ITEM varchar(10))
insert into MyTable Values
(1, 'aaa'),
(2, 'bbb'),
(4, 'ccc')

SELECT  t1.*, t2.number + 1 RepeatNumber
FROM    MyTable t1
JOIN    master.dbo.spt_values t2 ON t2.type = 'P' AND t2.number < t1.QTY
```

Here is the demo at: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d0c33cd5bbd6e5060988b6bf5efd4ff)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do as:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
(
    VALUES
    (1, 'aaa'),
    (2, 'bbb'),
    (4, 'ccc')
) T(Qty, Item) CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT Number
    FROM Master..SPT_VALUES
    WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND Number > 0 AND Number <= T.Qty
) TT(N)
```

Note: You can replace `master..spt_values` with a tally table.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Tally to do this, and then `JOIN` on `No` being greater or equal to the value in the Tally:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(SELECT MAX([No]) FROM dbo.mytable) --if 185 isn't to change, then I would replace the sub query with 185
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --216 rows, add more Ns here, or more NULLs above to make larger
SELECT mt.[No] AS QTY,
       mt.Item       
FROM dbo.mytable mt
     JOIN Tally T ON mt.[No] >= T.I;
```